# MySQL select using group and count for join tables

Tags: mysql, sql

For my project, I've a student table and a school table.

A student belongs to a company. A school has many students.

(A student's school_id is assigned NULL when that student graduates.)

```
The student table:
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | school_id  |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
The school table:
+----+------------+------------------------+
| id | city_id    | name                   |
+----+------------+------------------------+
```

The goal is to inner join these tables, count the students for each school, and order by the student number.

Comment: Don't forget the GROUP BY! (Step 1, JOIN. Step 2, GROUP BY. Step 3, ORDER BY.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following SQL query:

```
SELECT school.NAME, 
       count(student.id) AS Total_Student 
FROM   school 
       LEFT JOIN student 
              ON school.id = student.school_id 
GROUP BY school.id
ORDER BY Total_Student
```

Comment: Result of this: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column...

Comment: Yes i have added `group by`. My mistake i forgot.

Comment: Cool, just need to add ORDER BY Total_Student to make the answer complete. Thank you!

Comment: @NobleDinasaur Also note that this is a left join -- this means you will also get results for schools without students. With an inner join, as you required, these schools would be omitted. This might or might not be what you need.